# Inputing column values in one table from another related table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `Students` and `Course_Registrations` where each student registers several courses.

In my `students` table I have his/her degree(MS/BS) but it's missing in the `course_Registrations` table. I've tried the below code to get each student degree program in `course_registrations`  but I get this error:

*Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row*

Any suggestions?

```
Update  ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS
set ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.degree=
(
    Select ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.degree
    from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS
    where ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID=ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
)

where exists 
(
    select *
    from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS
    where ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID=ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
    GROUP BY STUDENT_ID      
 );
```

Comment: What database are you using?  When there is more than one match, which degree do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem because some students have multiple rows in `ISB_STUDENTS`. You need to figure out what to do to combine them.  In the meantime, I would suggest this:

```
Update  ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS
    set degree = (Select MAX(s.degree)
                  from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS s
                  where ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
                 )
    where exists (select 1
                  from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS s
                  where s.STUDENT_ID = ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
                  group by s.STUDENT_ID
                  having min(s.degree) = max(s.degree)
                 );
```

Note the use of the `having` clause in the subquery in the `where` clause.  This will set the value only when all the degrees on the student records are the same.  Then you can investigate two issues:

- In a table called `ISB_STUDENTS` why are there duplicate `STUDENT_ID`s?
- When there are such duplicates, how will you handle multiple inconsistent degrees?

Comment: Hey thanks! Yes you are right! StudentID 1 belongs to a BS as well as an MS student. I didn't keep that in mind! In student table I also have a previous degree column, can you help me with a command that will impute MS if previous degree was BS and BS if previous was high school? 

Thanks alot! Im working on a warehousing project so duplicate student IDs are there because I had to capture data from multiple sources into my staging area. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Update  ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS
set ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.degree=
(
    Select MAX(ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.degree)
    from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS
    where ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID=ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
)

where exists 
(
    select 1
    from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS
    where ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID=ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
 );
```

This correlated subquery is calculated for each row in `ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS`

```
Select ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.degree
from ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS
where ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID=ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.STUDENT_ID
```

So if it returns several rows for a certain `ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS.degree` it's not clear which one to set as a value.

Applying `MAX(ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS.degree)` to the all rows of this subquery guarantees there will only one row.

But you should be careful with this update. Maybe there are different courses a student attended and mybe there different degrees for each course.

Answer (score 0):

as i understood from your question, you have the following

1. student table that contains degree field
2. course_registration table that also contains degree field and you want to update it from student table for each student

if so, you can try this

```
Update r set r.degree=s.degree
from ROOT.ISB_COURSE_REGISTRATIONS r
inner join ROOT.ISB_STUDENTS s on r.STUDENT_ID=s.STUDENT_ID
```

if i misunderstood any of your requirements, please clarify it

hope this will help you